# What is the difference between defining a function outside useEffect and calling that function inside of it and defining a function inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, usecallback

I have few scenarios and I'd like to understand the differences in regards to **rendering** and performance.

The example shown below is for a simple function but please consider a more complex one too as well as an *async function*.

**Scenario 1: Defining function and calling it inside useEffect.**

```
useEffect(() => {
  function getBooks() {
    console.log('I get books!');
  }
  getBooks();
}, []);
```

**Scenario 2: Defining function outside UseEffect and calling it inside of it.**

```
function getBooks() {
  console.log('I get books!');
}
useEffect(() => {
  getBooks();
}, []);
```

**Scenario 3: Using useCallback to define the function outside of UseEffect and calling it inside of it.**

```
const getBooks = useCallback(() => {
  console.log('I get books!');
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  getBooks();
}, []);
```

**Scenario 4: Using useCallback to define a function inside UseEffect and calling it also inside UseEffect.**

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getBooks = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('I get books!');
  }, []);
  getBooks();
}, []);
```

Comment: It's not possible to use [`useCallback` inside `useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#:~:text=Instead%2C%20always%20use%20Hooks%20at,multiple%20useState%20and%20useEffect%20calls.) though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Case 1: `getBooks` only create once time inside the `useEffect`. And `getBooks` only create when `useEffect` was called.

Case 2: `getBooks` create on the component. And when the component re-render, `getBooks` is also re-create.

Case 3: It has the same case 2 but it only creates once time. It is like case 1. But we can customize dependencies for each. They will be independent of each other

Case 4: Wrong case. It's not possible to use `useCallback` inside `useEffect`: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: so case 3 is the best one in terms of performance and rendering wise?

Comment: If you only want to use `getBooks` inside the `useEffect`. Case 1 is the best